# Current Event of an XMLEventReader

Tags: java, iterator, stax

From [XMLEventReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/xml/stream/XMLEventReader.html#getElementText%28%29):

```
String getElementText()
Reads the content of a text-only element. 
Precondition: the current event is START_ELEMENT.
Postcondition: the current event is the corresponding END_ELEMENT.
```

What is the "current" event of an `XMLEventReader`, being referred here?

Is it the event that was returned by the last call for that reader:

a) to `nextEvent()`, or
b) to `peek()`?

From the answer of the previous question, how do you interpret this snippet from listing 2 of [StAX'ing up XML](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/xml/library/x-stax2/index.html):

```
while (reader.hasNext()) {
    XMLEvent event = reader.peek();
    if (event.isStartElement()) {
        StartElement start = event.asStartElement();
        if (ICON.equals(start.getName())) {
            System.out.println(reader.getElementText());
            break;
        }
    }
    reader.nextEvent();
}
```

I'm encountering a `ParseError: parser must be on START_ELEMENT to read next text`.

Answer (score 2):

Please be aware that `.peek()` does not read from the Stream. The Documentation for `.peek()` says:

> Check the next `XMLEvent` without reading it from the stream. Returns
>   null if the stream is at `EOF` or has no more `XMLEvents`. A call to
>   `peek()` will be equal to the next return of `next()`.

So, the position of your Pointer does not change. Therefore, you are probably not on a `START_ELEMENT`, but most probably at the `START_DOCUMENT`. Please call `.nextEvent()` instead of `.peek()`, that should make it work.

Good luck,
Max